# How to prioritize Git-Bash binaries on Windows

Tags: linux, cmd, path, find, git-bash

I have Git Bash installed on a Windows build agent and when running scripts, whenever I would use "find", it would run the DOS Find (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490906.aspx) instead of the Unix one. What is the best way to get my scripts to pick up the find.exe in, say C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin?

```
λ find /?
Searches for a text string in a file or files.

FIND [/V] [/C] [/N] [/I] [/OFF[LINE]] "string" [[drive:][path]filename[ ...]]
```

I have to explicitly state the path, or be in the bin directory when executing commands for it to pick up the Unix style find

```
λ "c:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\find.exe" --help
Usage: /usr/bin/find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I usually used a simplified PATH:

```
set G=c:\path\to\latest\git
set PATH=%G%\bin;%G%\usr\bin;%G%\mingw64\bin
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
```

If `GH` (the Git installation folder) is set *before* `Windows\System32`, the find from Git will be chosen over the default Windows one.

You can type `where find`, to check where that command is found.